# Наиболее короткий в python способ присваивания переменной считываемого значения при некотором условии

Tags: python

Рассмотрим следующую простую задачу

```
На вход компьютеру подаётся число. 
Его нужно положить в переменную x, только в том случае,
если число поданное на вход больше нуля.
```

В `c++` есть следующий вариант

```
cin >> n;
int x = (n > 0)?n : 0;
```

Посему, меня заинтересовал аналог этого в `python`, но хотелось бы сделать это в одну строчку и с одной переменной, не заводя дополнительно n, думаю это возможно средствами `python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аналогом вашего кода в питоне будет использование *тернарного оператора*, так же как и в `C++`, просто у него другой синтаксис:

```
n = int(input())
x = n if n > 0 else 0
```

Короче я не сообразил как, но есть вариант, да.

Comment: Да, такое решение я сразу и написал, но потом задумался, возможно ли сравнивать ввод без его сохранения (Извиняюсь, если это весьма тупо и примитивно, но все же было интересно)

Comment: Короче получится: `x = max(0, int(input()))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ааааа, точно. Бинго ))

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да!! Это именно то, что я искал!

Comment: А если вы думаете что я срезал угол (так и есть), то есть более универсальное (и страшное) решение: `x = (lambda n: n if n > 0 else 0)(int(input()))`. Любые условия на ваш вкус.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вторая конструкция мне уже непонятна, но она работает и выглядит тоже концептуально интересно! Даже интереснее Вашего первого варианта!

Comment: @NeoFanatic , я только в порядке упражнения. Дома не пытаться повторить! Детям не давать! :) Серьёзно: пишите как вам и другим понятно. Последний код уж больно неприятный.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А чем неприятен? Мы просто перед вводом пишем условие на вводимые данные, выглядит как достаточно удобная конструкция. Ну да, это скорее упражненчиский интерес, нежели какое-то практическое решение

Comment: @NeoFanatic , чего ради читабельный код из двух строк превращен в однострочку, которая требует специальных знаний? Овчинка выделки не стоит. Ну это не то место, где надо выкладывать все свои знания по Питону. Если только на собеседовании.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy и то, право, верно...)

Answer (score 0):

```
x if (x := int(input())) > 0 else 0
```

Comment: Не работает. 3.9

Comment: @Эникейщик, работает.

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1**

```
value = int(input())
x = value if value > 0 else x
```

если больше 0, то записываем значение иначе оставляем старое значение (как я понял по условию)